# SSRS to what visual element corresponde the <Drillthrough> rdl tag?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, rdl, drilldown

I have deleted a parameter and I get this error:

```
The DrillthroughParameters.Value expression for the 'Chart1' ...
```

So I found in the rdl code of my report the following xml:

```
   <Drillthrough>
       <ReportName>= Globals!ReportName</ReportName>
       <Parameter Name="exampleParam">
          <Value>=Parameters!exampleParam.Value</Value>
       </Parameter>
```

If I delete the missing parts I resolve the error but my doubt persists:
Where can I modify these parameters visually from Visual Studio?

Comment: You should be able to right click on the chart area, action and there should be a go to report.. you should see a list of parameters loaded against this report. Remove them from here and you should be good.

Comment: Those parameters keep even if I remove them from Series's Action parameters

Comment: Check your data sets and remove any references to the same parameter